# Redirect Email Bypassing Mx priority number - installing SSL

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, ssl-certificate, mx-record

I have client website hosted on my server but they use a different mail server not hosted with us, so we basically have

```
1.MX entry to their mail server IP with priority 10
2.DNS A record to mail.xxx.com their mail server 
3.DNS MX record with mail.xxx.com  with priority as 0
```

My problem comes when i try to install the SSL certificate it only sends to the

```
administrator@xxx.com
```

What i wanted to do is bypass their mail server for this email address only using DNS settings or MX priority number ..

is this possible or never ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible, MX records are only looked up for the domain -- the user part is not used nor available to the DNS server.